# How to follow/track a user from a mobile site to the shopping cart in a non mobile site

Tags: google-analytics

Assuming I have a mobile version of a given webpage at `m.example.com` and that the final check-out-process has to be done at `www.example.com` (don't ask me why ... it will be fixed in the future but I have to live with it for now).

I can easily analyse the conversion rate for visitors who start at `www.example.com` and buy something there. But I can not analyse the conversion rate for visitors who start at `m.example.com` and have to end their check-out-process at `www.example.com`.

How can I realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following article should show the right solution to your problem:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en